# Hide scroll bar when overlay is true

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Actually I have enabled scroll in my page but when the overlay sets to true scroll bar was still there.
How to hide the scroll when there is overlay over the page?

```css
.overlay{
    display: none;
    opacity:0.8;
    background-color:#ccc;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    z-index:1000;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="show_overlay_fn()">
CLICK HERE
</div>
<br>

<div id="overlay" class="overlay"></div>

<script>
function show_overlay_fn(){
 document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
}
</script>
lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to createlost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars v scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to createlost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars v scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars
```

Comment: document.getElementById("overlay").style.overflowX = "hidden";

Comment: @Álvaro Touzón - not work sir.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `element.style.overflow` and assign property-value for it . I also test with overlay click for enable overflow again .

```js
function show_overlay_fn(){
 document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.overflowY = 'hidden';
}
//click listener for overlay
document.getElementById('overlay').addEventListener('click',function(){
  document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.overflowY = 'auto';
});
```

```css
.overlay{
    display: none;
    opacity:0.8;
    background-color:#ccc;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    z-index:1000;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="show_overlay_fn()">
CLICK HERE
</div>
<br>

<div id="overlay" class="overlay"></div>

lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to createlost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars v scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to createlost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars v scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars
```

Comment: hi, im tried to change in js overflowX or overflowY but doest works, but seems doesnt works, thanks

Comment: It is working if you set `overflowY` , not `overflowX` . I updated using with overflowY .

Comment: Yes ! Is that what you need ?

Comment: document.getElementById("overlay").style.overflowY = "hidden"; for my demo doent works

Comment: Your scroll has appear because of **the long** text outside of `overlay` element .So you can't control by `overlay` style !!

Answer (score 0):

Add another class to freeze body

```
body.freeze-scroll {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Then add this on your click function

```
$('body').toggleClass('freeze-scroll');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this also by using `css()` on `click function`

```css
.overlay{
    display: none;
    opacity:0.8;
    background-color:#ccc;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    z-index:1000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overlay-click" onclick="show_overlay_fn()">
CLICK HERE
</div>
<br>

<div id="overlay" class="overlay"></div>

<script>
function show_overlay_fn(){
 document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
}


$('.overlay-click').click(function(){
  $('body').css("overflow","hidden")
});

</script>
lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to createlost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars v scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to createlost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars v scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars lost of text to create scrollbars
```